# Select2 Drop-Down is slow

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have created one web application to produce graph using php, mysql and highchart. All input selection for graph is drop down there are 4 input fields along with date range. it was working fast when the table has less data. Now the table has around 700 MB data so it is not working fast. Then we decided to move select2.js here it is working better. But still some what performance we need... now it takes 16 sec to bring drop down value.

Anyone could you please suggest me how will i get faster performance with select2.js file. if select query has to be optimized according to that please guide me to do that also. Following is the query to take distinct value,

**select distinct client from global_stats**

Comment: Add keys to the fields in which it takes place.
Add the LIMIT to the SQL query

Comment: hi... thanks for the reply. already limit i added in the select statement. there are four input fields namely client name, ip, port, variable. already variable column has index. what i did was based on clien name selection i bring the ip value in the ip drop down. this is same for port and variable also in AJAX call, please have a look on the following select statement, **`select distinct client from table where client like '%term%** **select distinct ip from table where client='' and ip like '%term%**

Comment: Remaining queries are  **select distinct port from table where client='' and ip='' and port like '%term%** **select distinct variable from table where client='' and ip='' and port='' and variable like '%term%** ... Now tell me for which column i have to add index|key?

Comment: Without the table schema from which you take the data difficult to answer ... What database is used?